# After dual boot with Win10, Elementary shows no gui

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows

Just did a dual boot with Win10 + Elementary. I see the grub2 menu. When i select *elementary os* it takes me further and I'm greeted with a  black screen.

I figure the gui failed. I can switch to terminal (alt+f1,f2).

I see errors like this, i have an nvidia graphics driver.

[installing elementary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V7Ii.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling fast boot in bios and windows.
Try reinstalling elementary OS with a freshly flashed USB stick.

Make sure the SHA256 matched with the ISO file you downloaded. This makes sure the ISO is not corrupted.

Steps on how to do that are here: https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation